# NodeJS with config package do not change env to production

Tags: node.js

I have this files and SO:

```
config/default.json
config/development.json 
config/production.json
SO: Win 10
```

when i change the environment i execute this command: set `NODE_ENV=production` and then run my app: `nodemon app.js`

then i get this response:

```
App:  API REST NODEJS COURSE - DEV
DB:  test-server-dev
Listen port 3000...
```

i should get this:

```
App:  API REST NODEJS COURSE - PROD
DB:  test-server-prod
Listen port 3000...
```

this is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config'); 
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); 

console.log('App: ',config.get('name')); 
console.log('DB: ',config.get('configDB.host'));

app.use(morgan('tiny'));

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('Hi from express!');
});
```